# Name build differently based on matrix OS in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

Running in a different OS, but actually macOS: https://github.com/vmactions/solaris-vm

```yml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [macos-latest, macos-10.15]

    name: ${{ matrix.os }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: SunOS deps
        id: build_test
        uses: vmactions/solaris-vm@v0.0.3
        with:
          prepare: pkgutil -y -i cmake
        if: matrix.os == 'macos-10.15'
```

Which makes:

[image: GitHub actions sidebar]

How do I make it appear as "SunOS" then "macOS" in the sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making name like this:

```
name: ${{ matrix.os == 'macos-10.15' && 'SunOS' || matrix.os }}
```

Comment: Ahhh the old bash trick. Yeah that should work

Comment: Ended up using `${{ matrix.os == 'macos-10.15' && 'SunOS' || matrix.os }}` - want to update your answer to that and I'll accept?

Comment: @AT I updated it